# python in Node.js using spawn don't have response

Tags: python, node.js, server, spawn

I am new to spawn and I try to get the user's input from my frontend to my Node.js and then pass it to my python sentiment analysis code. But when I try to use spawn to get access to my python, it didn't response. I very much appreciate your help. Thank you.

Here what I want to do is passing the json data from the frontend to /add function via Axio.

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let inputData = require('../models/inputData.model');
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
const sentence = req.body.sentence;

const newData = new inputData({sentence});

const pythonProcess = spawn('python3', ['C:\\Users\\70519\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\pythonserver.py', newData])

pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    res.json('I am here!')
    res.json(data.toString());
})
});
```

However, in my website console, I don't receive 'I am here' from res.json(). Is that mean my python code is not running?

Answer (score 1):

I see in your current code that you are handling an `async` behavior inside a synchronous function. You call on the `on` event, but you are not "waiting" for it to occur.

When you call the `on` event, you are setting a `callback` function called when the `data` from the `spawn` process is available. The problem is that the function has finished its execution before processing the `callback` call.

ExpressJS offers many ways to handle *asynchronous* procedures. I suggest you use [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to solve your current situation. Check this example on how to use them with Express:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const express = require('express')

const PORT = 3000

const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  // The command arguments are passed as an array of strings.
  const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/tmp'])

  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Listen to the `data` event on `stdout`.
    ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => resolve(`stdout: ${data}`))
    // Listen to the `data` event on `srderr`.
    ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => reject(`stdout: ${data}`))
  })
    .then((data) => {
      res.status(200).send(data)
      next()
    })
    .catch((err) => next(err))
})

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(err.message)
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send({error: err.message})
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`))
```

Also, you should check out [Express`s middleware* documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) to find more information on how they work.

*****: `middleware` is the name Express gives to functions that receive the request, response objects, and `next` function.